# Validating a SAML to authenticate a user

Tags: python, authentication, saml

I have been trying the get a SAML authentication to work for quite some time now and am unable to validate the SAML message.
Am I misunderstanding the whole process and should be and doing the whole thing differently?

I have been trying to use [SignXML](https://github.com/XML-Security/signxml) but if anyone can provide an implementation using other packages that is fine.

A [link to the verification method](https://github.com/XML-Security/signxml/blob/develop/signxml/__init__.py#L691) and [the docs](https://signxml.readthedocs.io/_/downloads/en/latest/pdf/).

#### Short summary of the process:

I login on a third party service that then redirects me to my website with a SAML token. The SAML is verified and I am logged in based on the information in the SAML.
The third party service has provided me with a cert chain(2 cer file) that I use to verify the integrity of the SAML received.

### A simplified version of the code I wrote:

```
xml_as_bytes = b64decode(token)
saml = ET.fromstring(xml_as_bytes)
trusted_cert_path = 'path to a .cer file containing two keys supplied by the creator of the SAML'
XMLVerifier().verify(data=saml, ca_pem_file=trusted_cert_path)
```

Throws the following error:

```
XMLVerifier().verify(data=saml, ca_pem_file=trusted_cert_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/signxml/__init__.py", line 864, in verify
    verify(signing_cert, raw_signature, signed_info_c14n, signature_digest_method)
signxml.exceptions.InvalidSignature: Signature verification failed: bad signature
```

I have tried splitting the files up in two and passing them in with the ca_path param, but gives me the following error.
Also tried them individually with the same error result.

```
InvalidCertificate(X509StoreContextError([20, 0, 'unable to get local issuer certificate']))
```

### The SAML response with information redacted to show layout of response.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ID="_15dcf5e1-495b-4dc3-98ac-874c8c7b7683" Version="2.0" IssueInstant="2021-08-24T13:16:20.6881029Z" Destination="https://my.website.test/login/">
   <Issuer xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">Innskraning</Issuer>
   <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
      <SignedInfo>
         <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
         <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
         <Reference URI="">
            <Transforms>
               <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
               <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
            </Transforms>
            <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
            <DigestValue>base64 digetst value</DigestValue>
         </Reference>
      </SignedInfo>
      <SignatureValue>base64 signature value</SignatureValue>
      <KeyInfo>
         <X509Data>
            <X509Certificate>base64 certificate</X509Certificate>
         </X509Data>
      </KeyInfo>
   </Signature>
   <Status>
      <StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success" />
   </Status>
   <Assertion xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" Version="2.0" ID="_acd5ee05-3f60-4595-a7f8-1dae1c2baf70" IssueInstant="2021-08-24T13:16:20.6881029Z">
      <Issuer>Innskraning</Issuer>
      <Subject>
         <NameID NameQualifier="issuer-website.test" />
         <SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer">
            <SubjectConfirmationData Address="127.0.0.1" NotOnOrAfter="2021-08-24T13:21:20.6881029Z" Recipient="https://my.website.test/login/" />
         </SubjectConfirmation>
      </Subject>
      <Conditions NotBefore="2021-08-24T13:15:50.6881029Z" NotOnOrAfter="2021-08-24T13:21:20.6881029Z">
         <AudienceRestriction>
            <Audience>my.website.test</Audience>
         </AudienceRestriction>
      </Conditions>
      <AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="2021-08-24T13:16:20.6881029Z">
         <SubjectLocality Address="127.0.0.1" />
         <AuthnContext>
            <AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:TLSClient</AuthnContextClassRef>
         </AuthnContext>
      </AuthnStatement>
      <AttributeStatement>
         <Attribute Name="UserSSN" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic" FriendlyName="Kennitala">
            <AttributeValue xsi:type="xsd:string">1234567890</AttributeValue>
         </Attribute>
      </AttributeStatement>
   </Assertion>
</Response>
```

Comment: "trusted_cert_path = 'path to a .cer file containing two keys supplied by the creator of the SAML'" - not sure what you meant by two keys? you need only public key to verify the signature.

Comment: It's a cert chain. If it does not contain both certificates I will get the following error `InvalidCertificate(X509StoreContextError([20, 0, 'unable to get local issuer certificate']))`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a whole lot more to the SAML protocol than verifying the signature.

I recommend using a [SAML stack](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/i-need-a-saml-stack-now-63d9691e2d43).

Then everything will be done for you.